# Plex Plugin for Music Videos - Python

Tags: python, video, plugins, metadata

I'm trying to edit a LastFM music plugin for Plex to make it work with music videos.  I'm almost there with lots of Googling and a few questions on here, but I am stuck on the fact that the artists seem to group together.

My videos are in the format "Artist - Title.ext" and I have set that as the metadata title but it still seems to group.

Even if I split the videos after they have grouped in Plex, they all have the name of the first video.

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here is the code.  If anyone can help then it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import lastfm, re, time, os, urllib

GOOGLE_JSON = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&userip=%s&rsz=large&q=%s+site:last.fm+inurl:music'

def Start():
  HTTP.CacheTime = CACHE_1WEEK

def GetPublicIP():
  return HTTP.Request('http://plexapp.com/ip.php').content.strip()

def GetGoogleArtist(artist):
  try:
    url = GOOGLE_JSON % (GetPublicIP(), String.Quote(artist.encode('utf-8'), usePlus=True))
    jsonObj = JSON.ObjectFromURL(url, headers={'Referer' : 'http://www.plexapp.com'}, sleep=0.5)
    if jsonObj['responseData'] != None:
      jsonObj = jsonObj['responseData']['results']
      if len(jsonObj) > 0:
        result = jsonObj[0]
        url = result['unescapedUrl'].replace('+','%20')
        return re.findall('/music/([^/]+)', url)[0]
  except:
    pass

  return None

def CallWithRetries(fun, *args):
  tries = 10
  while tries > 0:
    try:
      return fun(*args)
    except:
      tries = tries - 1
      if tries > 0:
        Log('Call failed, retrying')
        time.sleep(2)
      else:
        raise

class LastFmAgent(Agent.Movies, Agent.Artist):
  name = 'Music Video'
  languages = [Locale.Language.English, Locale.Language.Korean]

  def safe_strip(self, ss):
    """
      This method strips the diacritic marks from a string, but if it's too extreme (i.e. would remove everything,
      as is the case with some foreign text), then don't perform the strip.
    """
    s = String.StripDiacritics(ss)
    if len(s.strip()) == 0:
      return ss
    return s

  def search(self, results, media, lang):

    path = media.filename
    path = urllib.unquote(path)
    filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(path))[0]
    Log(filename)
    artist = filename.split(' - ')[0]
    artist = artist.lower()
    Log(artist)


    Log("Search for artist")
    CallWithRetries(self.findArtists, lang, results, media, artist)

    Log("If the artist starts with 'The', try stripping.")
    if artist.startswith('the '):
      try: CallWithRetries(self.findArtists, lang, results, media, artist[4:])
      except: pass

    Log("If the artist has an '&', try with 'and'.")
    if artist.find(' & ') != -1:
      try: CallWithRetries(self.findArtists, lang, results, media, artist.replace(' & ', ' and '))
      except: pass

    Log("If the artist has an 'and', try with '&'.")
    if artist.find(' and ') != -1:
      try: CallWithRetries(self.findArtists, lang, results, media, artist.replace(' and ', ' & '))
      except: pass

    try: highest_score = max([x.score for x in results])
    except: highest_score = 0

    if len(results) == 0 or highest_score < 85:
      artist_id = GetGoogleArtist(artist)
      google_artist = CallWithRetries(lastfm.ArtistInfo, artist_id)
      if google_artist:
        (url, name, image, listeners) = google_artist
        Log("Google said 'you should try %s' (ID: %s)." % (name, artist_id))
        if listeners > 250:
          results.Append(MetadataSearchResult(id=artist_id, name=name, thumb=image, lang=lang, score = 100-Util.LevenshteinDistance(name.lower(), artist.lower())))

    Log("Finally, de-dupe the results.")
    toWhack = []
    resultMap = {}
    for result in results:
      if not resultMap.has_key(result.id):
        resultMap[result.id] = True
      else:
        toWhack.append(result)
    for dupe in toWhack:
      results.Remove(dupe)

  def findArtists(self, lang, results, media, artist):
    score = 90
    for r in lastfm.SearchArtists(artist,limit=5)[0]:
      id = r[0]
      Log(id)

      # Skip artists without many listeners, they're probanly wrong.
      if r[3] < 1000 and id.find('+noredirect') == -1:
        Log("Skipping %s with only %d listeners." % (r[1], r[3]))
        continue

      if id.find('+noredirect') == -1:
        id = r[1]
        dist = Util.LevenshteinDistance(r[1].lower(), artist.lower())
        albumBonus = self.bonusArtistMatchUsingAlbums(media, artistID=id, maxBonus=5)
        id = String.Quote(id.encode('utf-8'))
        Log('artist: ' + artist + ' albumBonus: ' + str(albumBonus))
        Log('Artist result: ' + r[1] + ' id: ' + id + ' score: ' + str(score) + ' thumb: ' + str(r[2]))
        results.Append(MetadataSearchResult(id = id.replace('%2B','%20'), name = r[1], thumb = r[2], lang  = lang, score = score + albumBonus - dist))
      else:
        # Get a correction.
        Log('Getting correction to artist.')
        correctArtists = lastfm.CorrectedArtists(artist)
        for result in correctArtists:
          id = String.Quote(result[0].encode('utf-8'))
          dist = Util.LevenshteinDistance(result[0].lower(), artist.lower())
          results.Append(MetadataSearchResult(id = id.replace('%2B','%20'), name = result[0], lang  = lang, score = score - dist + 5))

      score = score - 2

  def bonusArtistMatchUsingAlbums(self, media, artistID, maxBonus=5):
    Log('bonusArtistMatchUsingAlbums')
    lastFM_artistAlbums = []
    for album in lastfm.ArtistAlbums(artistID):
      (name, artist, thumb, url) = album
      lastFM_artistAlbums.append(name.lower())
    if len(lastFM_artistAlbums) == 0: return 0 #no last.fm albums for the artist, so abort!
    bonus = 0
    for a in media.children:
      album = a.title.lower()
      for lfa in lastFM_artistAlbums:
        score = Util.LevenshteinDistance(lfa, album)
        #Log(lfa, album, score)
        if score <= 2: #pretty solid match
          bonus += 1
          if bonus == maxBonus: break
      if bonus == 0 and album[-1:] == ')': #if we got nothing, let's try again without anything in paranthesis [e.g.'limited edition'] 
        album = album[:album.rfind('(')].strip()
        for lfa in lastFM_artistAlbums:
          score = Util.LevenshteinDistance(lfa, album)
          #Log(lfa, album, score)
          if score <= 2: #pretty solid match
            bonus += 1
            if bonus == maxBonus: break
    return bonus

  def update(self, metadata, media, lang):
    artist = CallWithRetries(XML.ElementFromURL, lastfm.ARTIST_INFO % String.Quote(String.Unquote(metadata.id), True))[0]
    summary = artist.xpath('//bio/content')[0]
    metadata.title = String.Unquote(artist.xpath('//artist/name')[0].text, True)
    Log(metadata.title)
    filename = media.items[0].parts[0].file.decode('utf-8')
    cleanname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
    Log(cleanname)
    metadata.title = cleanname
    Log(metadata.title)
    Log("QWERTY")
    if summary.text:
      metadata.summary = decodeXml(re.sub(r'<[^<>]+>', '', summary.text))
    try:
      url = artist.xpath('//artist/image[@size="mega"]//text()')[0]
      if url not in metadata.posters:
        metadata.posters[url] = Proxy.Media(HTTP.Request(url))
    except:
      pass     
    metadata.genres.clear()
    for genre in artist.xpath('//artist/tags/tag/name'):
      metadata.genres.add(genre.text.capitalize())

def decodeXml(text):
  trans = [('&amp;','&'),('&quot;','"'),('&lt;','<'),('&gt;','>'),('&apos;','\''),('\n ','\n')]
  for src, dst in trans:
    text = text.replace(src, dst)
  return text
```